# Cassandra - Create a "read" version of a table in another cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I currently have two Cassandra Clusters (name it cluster A and cluster B) with different topologies. I have a table (named MY_TABLE) that is in cluster A.

Is there any way to create a replicated table on Cluster B as a "read only" table ? Which mechanism of synchronization could be used for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are different clusters, then you have a limited set of options:

- Bulk load data from one cluster to another via Spark, or something like. This approach has downside as data is not replicated in real-time
- Use [Advanced Replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/advReplication/advRepTOC.html) option of DataStax Enterprise

But you can implement such functionality in one cluster, consisting of 2 data centers:

- just expand necessary keyspaces into 2nd data center;
- create a role that will have [read-only access to table](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html#authorization).

Comment: What would make the role with read-only access only use the second data-center?